# Parametrization the curve of intersection of sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=5$ and cylinder $x^2+\left(y-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2$.

Tags: conic-sections, 3d, curves, parametrization

I've seen similar posts here but none of the answers helped me. I am trying to parametrize a curve of intersection of a (top half $z>0$) sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=5$ and cylinder $x^2+\left(y-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2$.
I tried $$x=\frac{1}{2}\cos t $$ $$y=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sin t$$ $$z=\sqrt{5-\left(\frac{1}{2}\cos t\right)^2-\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sin t\right)^2}=\sqrt{\frac{9}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\sin t}$$ for $t \in (0,2\pi)$,  but I don't think it is correct. Even if it was, is there a better (more simple) approach?

Note: I need to find the circulation of a field $F=(y+z,x-z,0)$ over this curve so I need a good parametrizatian so that I was able to integrate it.

Comment: I think you have to find a parametrization of the cylinder(the standard one ) and put it in the equation of the sphere this will give you the solution which is  a parameterization of two closed curve

Comment: What do you mean by "the standard one"?

Comment: any parametrization you can obtain of the cylinder as  a surface in$ \mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: try this one $(Rcos(t),\frac12 +Rsin(t),v )$ where $v\in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: I think I am not following. If I put this parametrization into the equation of the sphere, I get $R^2+R\sin(t)+v^2=\frac{19}{4}$, correct? But I need to parametrize the curve in terms of $x = ...$, $y=...$ and $z = ...$ so that I could put it in the $F$ field.

Comment: in your case $R=\frac 12$ so from the equation that you obtain you have the $z(t)$ and $x(t)=\frac12 cos(t), y(t)=\frac 12+ \frac12sin(t)$ and the $z$ comes from the equation that you obtain and this is a curve on the sphere

Comment: I think, you have an ellipse on the sphere, but you do need spherical trigonometry to determine it.

Comment: @Bernstein okay, thank you. So that leads to the parametrization I have already written in my question (post)?

Comment: @Piquito I am not sure what you mean, could you be more specific please?

Comment: @LaurenSin Yes bro, yes  this is the parametrization, you can verify this, take any point of this curve and you check that this point is one the sphere and on the cylinder

Comment: @Lauren Sin.- What I have wanted to express is that the ellipse of the case is not flat but is contained in a sphere but it is not improbable that such considerations are not necessary.(proyecting into the plan $x=0$ would be enough)

Answer (score 2):

Use the fact that the right-circular cylinder of radius $r$ centered at $(h, k)$ in the $xy$-plane can be parametrized by $\mathbf G(t, z) = \langle h + r \cos t, k + r \sin t, z \rangle$ by the Pythagorean Identity, i.e., $\cos^2 t + \sin^2 t = 1.$

Considering that we are in the intersection of the right-circular cylinder $(x - 0)^2 + \bigl(y - \tfrac 1 2 \big)^2 = \tfrac 1 4$ and the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 5,$ both of these equations hold. Using the parametrization $\mathbf G,$ we have that $x = \tfrac 1 2 \cos t$ and $y = \tfrac 1 2 + \tfrac 1 2 \sin t,$ hence plugging these identities into the equation $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 5$ gives rise to the equation $\tfrac 1 4 \cos^2 t + \tfrac 1 4 + \sin t + \frac 1 4 \sin^2 t + z^2 = 5.$ Of course, we can now solve for $z$ as a function $z(t)$ of $t.$

Our original parametriation $\mathbf G(t, z)$ can now be viewed as a parametrization $\mathbf G(t) = \langle \tfrac 1 2 \cos t, \tfrac 1 2 + \tfrac 1 2 \sin t, z(t) \rangle.$

---

One other way to parametrize the intersection of these surfaces is by spherical coordinates $x = \sqrt 5 \sin \phi \cos \theta,$ $y = \sqrt 5 \sin \phi \sin \theta,$ and $z = \sqrt 5 \cos \theta.$ By plugging these identities into the equation of the right-circular cylinder, we obtain the equation $$5 \sin^2 \phi \cos^2 \phi + 5 \sin^2 \phi \sin^2 \theta - \sqrt 5 \sin \phi \sin \theta + \frac 1 4 = \frac 1 4.$$ By the Pythagorean Identity, this simplifies to $5 \sin^2 \phi = \sqrt 5 \sin \phi \sin \theta.$ Considering that $0 \leq \phi \leq \pi,$ and $\sin \phi > 0$ whenever $0 \leq \phi < \pi,$ we can solve for $\sin \theta = \sqrt 5 \sin \phi$ whenever $0 < \phi < \pi.$ But this implies that $\theta = \arcsin(\sqrt 5 \sin \phi),$ and this is not desirable.

Comment: So now, that we have the equation for $\theta$ we would plug it into the parametrization of sphere and that would be our curve parametrization, correct?

Comment: Precisely. But be careful about the domain of the curves when plugging things in. Like one of the other answerers observed, the intersection of these two surfaces results in two separate curves, so you will have to use two different domains to parametrize or two different parametrizations.

Comment: And by domain of the curve you mean the interval for $\phi$?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly it.

Answer (score 1):

Sphere
$$ x^2 +y^2 + z^2= 5 \tag1 $$

simplify given second Cylinder equation

$$ x^2+y^2 -y=0 $$

Subtract

$$z^2+y = 5 \; \tag2 $$
To satisfy this relation now introduce parameter $t$
$$z^2 = 5 \cos^2 t,\;\tag3 $$
so that
$$ y = 5 \sin ^2 t \tag4 $$

From (1) and (4)

$$ z^2= 5 -x^2 -25 \sin ^4 t \tag 5 $$

Equate RHS of $z^2$ from (3) and (5) simplify  to find parametrization for $x$

$$ x = \sqrt{5 \sin^2 t (1-5 \sin^2 t )}\tag6$$
From(3)
$$ z= \sqrt 5 \cos t \tag 7$$

So parametrization for three coordinates

$$ (x,y,z)=\big( \sqrt{5 \sin^2 t (1-5 \sin^2 t )}, 5 \sin ^2 t ,\sqrt 5 \cos t \big) \tag8$$

where positive sign is taken before radical signs for top hemisphere.

Comment: How did you find the equations for $z^2$ and $y$? Did you just make them up so that it works? And what do you mean by "sum of squares relation"?

Comment: I have given more steps to explain.Hope ok now.

Answer (score 1):

A third alternative is using Stokes' theorem, parameterize the surface enclosed by the curve and integrate... And at first it seems like you are going to end up with a nicer integral

\begin{eqnarray}
&& \int_0^\pi d\phi \int_0^{\arcsin\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\sin(\phi)\right]} d\theta \, \left[5 \sin(\theta)\right] (\nabla \times F)\cdot(\sin\theta\cos\phi,\sin\theta\sin\phi,\cos\theta) =
\\
&& \int_0^\pi d\phi \int_0^{\arcsin\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\sin\phi\right]} d\theta \, \, 5 \sqrt{2} \sin^2 \theta \sin \left( \phi + \frac{\pi}{4}\right) \\
&&
\int_0^\pi d\phi \, \frac{1}{2} \left(\cos \phi + \sin \phi \right) \left\{ 5 \arcsin \left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\sin\phi\right] - \sin\phi \sqrt{5 - \sin^2\phi}\right\}
\end{eqnarray}

but, at least at first sight, it does not seem specially simpler than the integral you get in the line integrals.

[image: intersection]

Comment: That’s a great idea. But I am not following your parametrization (the intervals for $\phi$ and $\theta$). Could you please be more specific? When I tried, I got $\phi \in (0, \arctan \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}})$ and for $\theta$ I’d say$\theta \in (- \arcsin(\sqrt{5}\sin \phi),  \arcsin(\sqrt{5}\sin \phi))$. Note that I am trying to parametrize the surface of one of the surfaces (the top one).

Answer (score 0):

The cylinder is

$$x^2+y^2=y,$$ implying (by the equation of the sphere)

$$y+z^2=5.$$

In terms of $y$,

$$\begin{cases}x^2=y-y^2,\\z^2=5-y.\end{cases}$$

Anyway, I don't know what you expect from a "good parameterization". (Will be hard to find a continuous parameterization that describes the two disconnected curves.)

Comment: I am trying to describe only one curve (since I have only a half of a sphere) see in my post (question).